# Window sliding a substring in Python dataframe columns

Tags: python

I have a sequence 'DEFGHI**JKLM**NOPQRS' as a row in a column which is also a substring of another column in a data frame.

Start Position of J = 7 and M = 10.

I need to create a new column such that it takes 5 letters before and after the start letter from J till M i.e. having a total length of 11:

EFGHI**J**KLMNO
FGHIJ**K**LMNOP
GHIJK**L**MNOPQ
HIJKL**M**NOPQR

I have tried this using R. I need suggestions to do the same in python for practice

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
s = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
i = s.index('J')
j = s.index('O')
context = 7
for mid in range(i, 1+j):
    print(s[mid-context:mid+context+1])
```

Output:

```
CDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ
DEFGHIJKLMNOPQR
EFGHIJKLMNOPQRS
FGHIJKLMNOPQRST
GHIJKLMNOPQRSTU
HIJKLMNOPQRSTUV
```

Comment: How do we do the same if the string is a row in a column and also a substring of another column? Example :

Column 1:   OPQRS    
Column 2:   HIJKLMNOPQRSTUV

Comment: @RamJonnalagedda That's an entirely different question.

Comment: Can you please help me with that as well? I need each of that entry in a new row of the column

Comment: @RamJonnalagedda Maybe, maybe not, depends on whether I see and am interested in the new, different question you should ask.

Comment: I did change the question. Please see if you can work it out

Comment: @RamJonnalagedda Please undo your edit and ask a **new** question. I refuse to edit my answers to keep up with moving goalposts.

Comment: I **cannot** add a new question until tomorrow and I am in a rush right now. Thanks though